# Раскрытие макроса в строку

Tags: c

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695078/5376639) описывается как организовать автоинкремент версии файла.

В частности там есть такие строки

```c
#define VERSION_MAJOR 1
#define VERSION_MINOR 0
#define VERSION_PATCH 0
#define VERSION_BUILD 0

#define stringify(a) stringify_(a)
#define stringify_(a) #a
```

и потом использование

```c
VALUE "FileVersion", stringify(VERSION_MAJOR) "." stringify(VERSION_MINOR) "." stringify(VERSION_PATCH) "." stringify(VERSION_BUILD)
```

Все работает, но я не пойму как. Как работает здесь макрос `stringify`?

Причем если объявить его так

```c
#define stringify(a) #a
```

То тогда в FileVersion записывается строка `VERSION_MAJOR.VERSION_MINOR.VERSION_PATCH.VERSION_BUILD`

Что это за конструкция такая `#a` и почему ее нужно вкладывать в другой макрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#a` - это конструкция препроцессора (это важно, так как он деюре работает до компилятора), которая значит ровно одно - замени `#a` на `"a"`.

Когда Вы пишите

```
#define stringify(a) #a
VERSION_MAJOR(VERSION)
```

то препроцессор именно это и делает - он просто подставляет и получается `"VERSION"`.

Когда же используется первый, правильный способ, то в первую итерацию раскрывается вот так

```
stringify(VERSION_MAJOR) "."
```

превращается в

```
stringify_(1) "."
```

и препроцессор обнаруживает, что там ещё есть макросы и делает вторую иттерацию

```
"1" "."
```

а потом уже такие строки склеиваются в

```
"1."
```

Comment: Спасибо. А имеет значение порядок объявления `stringify` и `stringify_`?

Answer (score 5):

[Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/cpp/Stringification.html) поясняет что `#a` превращает свой аргумент в строку. Но есть особенность:

> Unlike normal parameter replacement, the argument is not
> macro-expanded first. This is called stringification.

Аргумент не вычисляется перед превращением в строку. Это приводит к тому что `stringify_(VALUE)` раскрывается в `"VALUE"`.

А если раскрывать `stringify(VALUE)`, то перед передачей во вложенный макрос параметр раскроется и получится `stringify_(1)`, который затем раскроется в `"1"`.

Двойная вложенность заставляет препроцессор вычислить значение до стрингификации.

Попробуйте сами:

```
#define VALUE 1234
#define stringify(a) stringify_(a)
#define stringify_(a) #a

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    puts(stringify_(VALUE));
    puts(stringify(VALUE));
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc stringify.c && ./a.out 
> VALUE
> 1234
> ```

Вам, наверно, интересно почему препроцессор везде вычисляет параметры а при стрингификации нет? Чтобы работали такие штуки:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DUMP(expr) printf("%s = %d\n", #expr, (expr))
#define VALUE 42

int main() {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    DUMP(a + b);
    DUMP(VALUE);
    DUMP(a + b + VALUE);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc stringify.c && ./a.out 
> a + b = 5
> VALUE = 42
> a + b + VALUE = 47
> ```